# String keeps on repeating until randint provides the correct answer.

Tags: python

I'm trying to create this simple game but I'm having trouble. Here's the code, it keeps on looping the different answers. Please excuse the terrible story, could someone please help?

The code should quick if the option is equal to the correct (answer). But it doesn't, it just keeps looping both options until it hits the correct one.

```
import random


def options():
    print()
    print("What do you do?")
    print("1. Check the local bakery to see if the criminal is hiding in the oven.")
    print("2. Search the forest to see if he's made a quick getaway.")
    print("3. Check with the innkeeper to see if anyone has come in recently.")
    print("4. Search the sewers, this criminal scum will do anything for money.")
    print("9. Quit.")



print("On a dark and rainy night the town of Ogalu was quietly sleeping. On this night, a criminal \nwas amidst the sleeping people he sought to steal the King's crown and make himself rich."
        "The criminal named Zalox snuck into the palace, and stole the crown without alerting the guards. \nAfter this he ran away, but you, Bob the guard, heard something. You went to check the king"
        "he was safe, you then went to check the crown. They were gone!, you alert the townsguard and set \nout to catch this criminal scum.")
correct = random.randint(1,4)
options()
option = int(input("What option: "))
while option != 9:
    if option == 1:
        if correct == option:
            print("You make your way into the local bakery, you hear something drop. You turn around and there he is, the theif, in the local oven. You arrest him and put him in jail!")
        else:
            print("As you search the bakery you think you hear something near the oven, as you check it out you realise it's just a mouse. The theif isn't here!")

    elif option == 2:
        if correct == 2:
            print("As you make your way towards the forest you see a shadow limping away, it's the theif! You chase after him and catch him, you send him to jail for life!")
            break
        else:
            print("You head towards the forest, you think you hear something moving in the bushes, as you check it out a giant wolf chases you out of the forest, the theif isn't here")
    elif option == 3:
        if correct == 3:
            print("You approach the innkeeper and ask if anyone suspicious has been staying there, the innkeeper says a man came in recently in a hurry, he's in his room. You dart upstairs, burst into his room"
                    "and arrest him!")
            break
        else:
            print("You see the innkeeper walking his dog, you ask if anyone suspicious has been stayig with him, he says no. The theif isn't here")

    elif option == 4:
        if correct == 4:
            print("You search the old, dirty, smelly sewers looking for the thief, in the distance you see a light and a person running. It's the thief! You take a shortcut and pounce on him! You put him to jail!")
            break
        else:
            print("As you search the sewers you see nothing but smelly, dirty, sewage. Maybe the theif won't do anything for money. This was a bad idea, you make your way out the next exit")

print("Congratulatious! You saved the King's crown by capturing the theif know as Zalox. He's sentanced to life in jail. The town can finally relax again! You are know as Hero of Ogalu!")
```

Comment: For the sake of posterity, could you indent the `options` function?

Comment: @mgilson: done.  You could've done it for him, y'know.

Comment: @BrianCain -- Yeah, but reading posts on Meta, it seems that editing code in questions is extremely frowned upon for some reason.  I'm not sure about trivial edits such as this though...maybe I'll ask a question there about it.

Comment: Ok, good point, I can see exactly why now... :(

Comment: @BrianCain -- Here's the meta question ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141835/editing-code-in-question ) -- we can follow it to see how it turns out.  Also, as a side note, you wouldn't happen to know how to get a link in a comment would you?

Comment: You just did it, man.  Now a link with [replaced text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141835/editing-code-in-question) -- that requires \[replaced text\]\(url\)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14722/discussion-between-brian-cain-and-mgilson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the loop conditional on changes to `option`'s value, but only assign to that name outside of the loop:

```
option = int(input("What option: "))
while option != 9:
```

Move it inside the `while` loop instead (also make sure that `option`'s initial assignment satisfies the condition of the `while` loop!).

Also, unsolicited advice: you'll be blown away once you leverage the power of the `dict`ionary.  It's just great stuff.  Map those choices to strings or objects or functions to be invoked, and it might be clearer and/or more scale-able.

Comment: Too quick!  I was sitting there thinking -- Well, all the break statements look like they're in the right places ...  Hmm... I had just figured it out when I saw you had posted and beat me to it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've honestly been changing that code for about 3 hours trying to get it to work! I'm so stupid.